# Dynamic website database access by admin

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to make a dynamic website for my friend  for his shop of "computer solutions".
Now I know that it would require a database .But i dont know how the interface (for updating data in db)
would be access by the admin only and will it be different from the other guests' interface which is required only to ask questions .
I mean the interface of admin should be different from the interface of other users.
This  would be my first dynamic website.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have RBAC(Role Based Access Control). In the table of users in db, assign roles to them such as who is admin, who is editor,etc. Then, simply check the username, password, and role and then redirect the user to the respective page. Also in the admin page itself you should keep a check whether user is logged in and has the role of admin.

The role check may look something like this:

Add Groups column in your users table and check the value when user logged in successfully.

```
<?PHP
#........... after login success
$Groups = $result["Groups"];
if($Groups == 1){ // "Admin"
// redirect/include admin page
}else if($Groups == 2){
// redirect/include normal user page
}
?>
```

Comment: ya ur right bt i want only admin can see login pg and no other user can login
also other users are only required to ask question which they can ask just by writing their question and email id

Comment: Yes the answer satisfies those requirements.